# On Click event not working after loading element through Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading the page (contains the javascript), and then I am loading the PartialView (contains the table). The problem is, I can't select the table id or the onClick event does not fire.

Index.cshtml

```
$('#sortingRow').on('click', 'th a', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'GET',
        data: { sortOrder: sortOrder },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#sortingRow').parent().html(result);
            LoadSampleDesign();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

_PartialView.cshtml

```
<table>
    <tr id="sortingRow">
        <th>
            <a href="link">Click Me</a>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

That partialView is being loaded using Ajax, like this:

```
$(sections).on('click', '#sectionPageLinks a', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#sectionPageLinks').parent().html(result);
            LoadSampleDesign();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I've tried JsFiddle and the javascript seems to be working correctly. Also, At first, you might think the problem is that jquery couldn't find the table since it was being loaded after DOM completed, but that's why I'm using "on()", doesn't that make it live so it should be able to find the #table even after DOM was completed.

Comment: Is the event handler being called after the partial loads? If not, the events can't be attached to elements that was not rendered in the dom yet.

Comment: On success function of the load, I've attempted this: $('#sortingRow').bind('click');

Comment: When you specify your handler here: `$('#sortingRow').on('click', 'th a'`, are you certain that `#sortingRow` has been loaded into the DOM at that point? It needs to exist, the `th a` elements do not.

Comment: If I got it right, the first code snippet should be called after(its means in the `success`) of the last code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading the partial view via Ajax the click event is no longer bound. Change your row click event as follows.

<s>`$('#sortingRow').on('click', 'th a', function () {`</s>

```
$(document).on('click', '#sortingRow th a', function () {
```